# How did Dumbledore and Grindelwald not get repercussions when their 3-way duel with Aberforth erupted?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

If Gellert Grindelwald and Albus Dumbledore

> made a blood pact,

how did they both not die or receive magical repercussions when the 3-way duel between Aberforth, Albus, and Gellert broke out?

Gellert Grindelwald and Albus Dumbledore both

> swore to never fight each other,

so how did they duel each other with no repercussions when the duel between Albus Dumbledore, Aberforth Dumbledore, and Gellert Grindelwald happened?

> (the duel that killed Ariana Dumbledore)

Since Albus Dumbledore and Gellert Grindelwald part ways after the 3-way duel and don’t see each other until their 1945 legendary duel, they had to have made the pact before Aberforth found out and confronted them about their plans for the future, which means that they

> made their blood pact before

the 3-way duel erupted?

Comment: We don’t know what they swore with their blood pact. We also don’t know whether they actually _fought each other_ as teenagers – Aberforth and Grindelwald definitely fought each other, but Albus was presumably mostly trying to break up the fight.

Comment: I’d be very surprised if this isn’t revealed in one of the upcoming films. As such this probably falls foul of the future world policy.

Comment: Also please be mindful of spoilers for other users.

Comment: It's not clear how the blood-pact works. It might just make spells bounce off of each other which would explain Ariana's death

Comment: what if they made a pact after their duel ?

Comment: It did have repercussions, it killed Arianna.